# An initially sparse matrix would not turn new zero values into sparse

Tags: r, matrix, zero, sparse-matrix

As I am working with huge data sets, I receive my data already sparse. I load it in the regular way and my matrix 'smskin' is of the class:

```
    Formal class 'dsCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 7 slots
      ..@ i       : int [1:57263] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
      ..@ p       : int [1:26018] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
      ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 26017 26017
      ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
      .. ..$ : NULL
      .. ..$ : NULL
      ..@ x       : num [1:57263] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
      ..@ uplo    : chr "U"
      ..@ factors : list()
```

My matrix is 26000x26000 and all diagonal values are 1 although I want to get rid off them to save some additional space. Thus I do
diag(smskin) = 0
Now, to save some more space I want to turn those zero values into . sparse positions.
So I do
new.smskin = Matrix(smskin,sparse=TRUE)
However, when I look to the output of the diagonal, the result is

```
    10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
        [1,] 0 . . . . . . . . .
        [2,] . 0 . . . . . . . .
        [3,] . . 0 . . . . . . .
        [4,] . . . 0 . . . . . .
        [5,] . . . . 0 . . . . .
        [6,] . . . . . 0 . . . .
        [7,] . . . . . . 0 . . .
        [8,] . . . . . . . 0 . .
        [9,] . . . . . . . . 0 .
        [10,] . . . . . . . . . 0
```

It appears that the 0 values are not accepted as sparse.
I am not sure of what I need to do, but I really need this diagonal to be sparse as well.

Best,
Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why this sometimes happens.  However, there is a function that is provided in the `Matrix` package to fix it:  `drop0`.

```
smskin<-drop0(smskin)
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, but if you multiply this by a logical mask of itself, it will fix the problem:

```
#Setting up smskin
smskin<-rsparsematrix(nrow=26000,ncol=26000,density=0)
diag(smskin)<-1
str(smskin)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:26000] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:26001] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 26000 26000
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:26000] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
#
diag(smskin)<-0
str(smskin)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:26000] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:26001] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 26000 26000
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num [1:26000] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
smskin<-((smskin!=0)*smskin)
str(smskin)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int(0) 
  ..@ p       : int [1:26001] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 26000 26000
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : NULL
  ..@ x       : num(0) 
  ..@ factors : list()
```